# Using variable path and file name to write.csv issue

Tags: r, file

Newbie question. I am trying to write a df to CSV.  I want to specify the output file name at run time and then write it to the current working directory. It can be any df, so I'll skip that and show the code that is hanging me up.

`varNewName = readline(prompt = "Name the file :")` # prompt for a file name for output
`varPath = getwd()`  #capture current path for prefixing output file
`varFileName <- paste0(varPath,"/",varNewName).` # concatenate path and user input file name. `print(varFileName)`  # just print to confirm it is a well formed path and filename.

which yields this

`[1] "/Users/myname/projects/farmCSV/testoutput.csv"`

**Ok, now the part that is driving me nuts.**

*this does not error out, but does not produce an output file that I can find*
`write.csv(dfTemp, varFileName)`

*# this does not error out, but does not produce an output file that I can find*
`write.csv(dfTemp, c(varFileName))`

*# this produces a data.csv file in the working directory, but it is hard coded.*
`write.csv(dfTemp, file = "~/Documents/projects/farmCSV//data.csv")`

Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Comment: After you run your code in full, what is the result of `file.exists(varFileName)`. This will verify within R whether a file has been written with that name.

Comment: Note: instead of `paste0(varPath,"/",varNewName)` use `file.path(varPath, varNewName)`

Comment: Your hard-coded path is in `~/Documents/projects/farmCSV` but your constructed path is at `Users/myname/projects/farmCSV/`. Does that latter path actually exists, and is that where you’ve been looking?

Comment: @RicVillalba - thank you. That solved it. Stupid user problem.  ;)